# How do I use react context with react-navigation

Tags: react-native, socket.io, react-navigation, react-context

I am trying to keep socket.io instance through all the app is mounted.

I am using react-native, socket.io and react-navigation.

So I need to react context, to keep my socket.io instance within all child component.

So kindly help me how can I use react context with react navigation, and also how can I update the context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that is so easy, just create a file example: `ctx.js`

then inside this file add the following code:

```
import React from 'react';
export const { Provider, Consumer } = React.createContext();
```

then in your root Component import Provide and put `Provider` as root Component
like below:

```
 <Provider value={this.state}>
 </Provider>
```

then in any component you gonna use the context just import the Consumer like below:

```
class A extends Component{
 ....
}
const AComponent = props => (
    <Consumer>
        {context => <A {...props} context={context} /> }
    </Consumer>
);
```

Comment: Thank you thats great and I am did the same